# .append() not working when using phonegap

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm currently creating a phonegap app that receives data from an API. I make use of ajax to retrieve the information and then append that information to a div. Now this workings fine in the browser but when I do this in android using phonegap nothing seems to happen and no information is appended to the div. Here is the code:

```
$.getJSON(
        AddressAccess+"Home/loginitems/email/"+UserEmailAddress+"/format/json",
        function(data)
        {
          $('#updateprofilename').append(data[0].Name);
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say, that u're using $('.selector').append(something) - you're using jQuery Mobile for dynamic generation of markup.

When dynamically adding content (lets say a `<div>` to another `<div>` you have to refresh your content by doing something like this: `$('[data-role="content"]').trigger('create');` in order to update your page-content after dynamic enhancemant.

more simple:

you have a `<div>` and you're dynamicly adding another `<div>`:

```
$("#YourWrapperDiv_ID").append('<div id="DynAddDiv_ID">My dynmicly added content</div>');
$("#YourWrapperDiv_ID").trigger('create');
```